# JAXB SAXParseException when unmarshalling document with relative path to DTD

Tags: xml, jaxb, dtd

I have a class that unmarshals xml from a 3rd party source (I have no control over the content). Here is the snippet that unmarshals:

```
JAXBContext jContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.optimumlightpath.it.aspenoss.xsd"); 
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jContext.createUnmarshaller() ;
StringReader xmlStr = new StringReader(str.value);
Connections conns = (Connections) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStr);
```

`Connections` is a class generated dtd->xsd->class using xjc. The package `com.optimumlightpath.it.aspenoss.xsd` contains all such classes.

The xml I recieve contains a relative path in the DOCTYPE.  Basically `str.value` above contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE Connections SYSTEM "./dtd/Connections.dtd">
<Connections>
...
</Connections>
```

This runs successfully as a java 1.5 application.  In order to avoid the error above,  I had to create a ./dtd directory off the project root and include all the dtd files (not sure why I had to do this but we'll get to that).

I've since created a web service on Tomcat5.5 that uses the above class.  I am getting `[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Relative URI "./dtd/Connections.dtd"; can not be resolved without a document URI.]` on the unmarshal line.  I have tried creating ./dtd in every relavant folder (project root, WebContent, WEB-INF, tomcat working dir, etc) to no avail.

Question #1:  Where can I locate ./dtd so that the class can find it when run as a tomcat webservice?  Is there any tomcat or service config I need to do in order to get the directory recognized?

Question #2:  Why does the class even need the dtd file in the first place?  Doesn't it have all the information it needs to unmarshal in the annotations of the dtd->xsd->class? I've read many posts about disabling validation, setting EntityResource, and other solutions, but this class isn't always deployed as a web-service and I don't want to have two code trains.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When unmarshalling from an InputStream or Reader the parser does not know the systemId (uri / location) of the document, so it can not resolve relative paths. It seems the parser tries to resolve references using the current working directory, which only works when running from the ide or command line. In order to override this behaviour and do the resolving yourself you need to implement an `EntityResolver`, as Blaise Doughan mentioned.

After some experimenting I found a standard way of doing this. You need to unmarshal from a `SAXSource`, which is in turn constructed from an `XMLReader` and an `InputSource`. In this example the dtd is located next to the annotated class and so can be found in the classpath.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    private static final String FEATURE_NAMESPACES = "http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces";
    private static final String FEATURE_NAMESPACE_PREFIXES = "http://xml.org/sax/features/namespace-prefixes";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, IOException, SAXException {
        JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = ctx.createUnmarshaller();

        XMLReader xmlreader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
        xmlreader.setFeature(FEATURE_NAMESPACES, true);
        xmlreader.setFeature(FEATURE_NAMESPACE_PREFIXES, true);
        xmlreader.setEntityResolver(new EntityResolver() {
            public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
                // TODO: Check if systemId really references root.dtd
                return new InputSource(Root.class.getResourceAsStream("root.dtd"));
            }
        });

        String xml = "<!DOCTYPE root SYSTEM './root.dtd'><root><element>test</element></root>";
        InputSource input = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        Source source = new SAXSource(xmlreader, input);

        Root root = (Root)unmarshaller.unmarshal(source);
        System.out.println(root.getElement());
    }
}
```

**Root.java**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {
    @XmlElement
    private String element;

    public String getElement() {
        return element;
    }

    public void setElement(String element) {
        this.element = element;
    }
}
```

**root.dtd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT root (element)>
<!ELEMENT element (#PCDATA)>
```

Comment: Jorn - ty for your response.  I am trying Blaise's suggestion first as it requires the least code changes.  But you both have provided very helpful answers.  Is there a way I can credit both?

Comment: My approach will work, but the advantage of Jorn's approach is that you stay JAXB implementation agnostic which is the most portable solution.

Answer (score 2):

> Question #2: Why does the class even
>   need the dtd file in the first place?

It is not the JAXB implementation that is looking for the DTD, it is the underlying parser.

> Question #1: Where can I locate ./dtd
>   so that the class can find it when run
>   as a tomcat webservice?

I'm not sure, but below I'll demonstrate a way you can make this work using the [MOXy JAXB](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) implementation (I'm the tech lead) that will work in multiple environments.

**Proposed Solution**

Create an EntityResolver that loads the DTD from the classpath.  This way you can package the DTD with your application and you will always know where it is regardless of the deployment environment.

```
public class DtdEntityResolver implements EntityResolver {

    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)
            throws SAXException, IOException {
        InputStream dtd = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dtd/Connections.dtd");
        return new InputSource(dtd);
    }

}
```

Then using the MOXy JAXB implementation you can cast down to the underlying implementation and set the EntityResolver.

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBHelper;
...
JAXBContext jContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.optimumlightpath.it.aspenoss.xsd");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jContext.createUnmarshaller() ;
JAXBHelper.getUnmarshaller(unmarshaller).getXMLUnmarshaller().setEntityResolver(new DtdEntityResolver());
StringReader xmlStr = new StringReader(str.value);
Connections conns =(Connections) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStr);
```

Comment: Blaise - ty for taking the time to respond. Initially, JAXBHelper complained that the unmarshaller was not an eclipselink unmarshaller.  So I replaced javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext with org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext and javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller with org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller.  However, the eclipselink JAXBContext returns a javax JAXBContext type. JAXBUnmarshaller requires a eclipselink type and I am getting cast exceptions if I try to re-cast.  Any ideas?

Comment: You need to add a file named jaxb.properties file in with your model classes with the following entry:  javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory

Comment: I may try that at another time.  I was able to make Jorn's answer work although it will require more code changes. As you say it is the most portable.  Thank you both very much!!  When I get a 15 rep, I can vote up your answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another variation on the answers already been given using the `EntityResolver` interface. My situation was resolving relative external XML entities from one XML file to another in a folder hierarchy. The parameter to the constructor below is the XML "working" folder, not the working directory of the process.

```java
public class FileEntityResolver implements EntityResolver {
    private static final URI USER_DIR = SystemUtils.getUserDir().toURI();

    private URI root;

    public FileEntityResolver(File root) {
        this.root = root.toURI();
    }

    @Override @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
        URI systemURI;
        try {
            systemURI = new URI(systemId);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            return null;
        }

        URI relative = USER_DIR.relativize(systemURI);
        URI resolved = root.resolve(relative);

        File f = new File(resolved);
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        // SAX will close the file reader for us
        return new InputSource(fr);
    }
}
```